# Intuition on how to exchange finite sums

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am asked to prove the following
$$\sum_{r=1 (r,q)=1}^{q}f(r)=\sum_{d|q}\mu(d)\sum_{s=1}^{q/d}f(ds)$$
I assume this can be proven by exchanging the sums. However, this made me realize I never really understood how to exchange finite sums like this. How I do it is I list all combinations and then I try to notice how to exchange the sum.
For example, take a simple $q$ say $q=p_1p_2$ $p_1<p_2$. Normally the summation is as such
$$(1,1)\cdots (1,p_1)\cdots(1,p_2)\cdots(1,p_1p_2)$$
$$(p_1,1)\cdots (p_1,p_1)\cdots(p_1,p_2)$$
$$(p_2,1)\cdots(p_2,p_1)$$
$$(p_1p_2,1)$$
Now I stare at this untill i can see how to revert the sum.
In this case I think it turns into $$\sum_{s=1}^{q}\sum_{d|q \text{s.t $d<\frac{q}{s}$}}$$
Is this correct? Also, how else should i arrive at this answer without listing the numbers. It takes too long and can be hard for me

EDIT: Perhaps this is a wrong example, as you do not want to exchange the sums but my question still stands, how do I know how to exchange such sums, without writing out an example like I have shown above.

Comment: This is a version of the classical Möbius inversion formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula where $\mu$ is the Möbius function.

Comment: @JeanMarie We do not know $f$ is multiplicative?

Comment: This is an amazing learning moment ... Möbius inversion works for any arithmetic function whatsoever, not just multiplicative functions! (Check the proof to confirm this!)

Comment: @GregMartin I have just realized this! I was under the impression drichlet convolution forms a group for multiplicative functions. It seems it is a subgroup of a much larger group! That is very interesting.

Comment: @JeanMarie I just realized that the RHS cannot be a convolution of two arithemtic functions as there is no arithmetic function $g$ such that $g(q/d)=\sum_{1}^{\frac{q}{d}}f(ds)$

Comment: I just open my laptop now. You look right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I see the process of "exchanging" (well, rearranging) the sums. The LHS is $\sum_{r\in A}f(r)$ over some set $A$ (assume $q$ fixed), the RHS is $\sum_{(d,s)\in B}\mu(d)f(ds)$ over some set $B$. So, we group the terms on the RHS with $ds=r$, for each possible $r$ (that is, for $1\leqslant r\leqslant q$). What are $(d,s)\in B$ with $ds=r$? We see that $d$ must divide *both* $q$ and $r$, and each such $d$ determines $s=r/d$ uniquely. This means $$\sum_{d\mid q}\mu(d)\sum_{s=1}^{q/d}f(ds)=\sum_{r=1}^q f(r)\sum_{d\mid(q,r)}\mu(d).$$ (Now recall that $\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)$ is $1$ if $n=1$ and is $0$ otherwise.)

Comment: Similarly, for exchanging the summations over $d$ and $s$ as in the question, the "strategy" is first to find *all* the possible values of $s$ (in our case $1\leqslant s\leqslant q$), then the possible values of $d$ *for each of these* $s$ (in our case $d\mid q$ with $d\leqslant q/s$).